# C++ inheritance loop dependency

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am porting some C# code to C++ and have the following problem, see the simplified code below. My filesystem class depends on the directory class which in return inherits from the filesystem class. This seems to work in `C#` but not in `C++`. Is there a simple trick to break this?

```
class fileSystemItem{
    private:
    Directory* parent;
};

class Directory : public fileSystemItem{

};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A forward declaration of `directory`:

```
class Directory;
class FileSystemItem{
    private:
    Directory* parent;
};

class Directory : public FileSystemItem{

};
```

Note the consistent capitalization.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in C++, every type has to be declared before you can refer to it. In order to fix this, you can perform a so-called *forward declaration*, declaring the sub-class before its first appearance in the base class.

Just add the line `class Directory;` before the definition of `fileSystemItem`. Also note that, in your example, you've spelled `Directory` differently (in regards to capitalization) in the definition of `Directory` itself and its use in the definition of `fileSystemItem`. This won't work, as identifiers (just like in C#) are case-sensitive.

Your resulting declarations should look like this:

```
class Directory;
class fileSystemItem{
    private:
    Directory* parent;
};

class Directory: public fileSystemItem{

};
```